# How does "she told the publication" make sense in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> “The past six months have been incredibly difficult for me,” **she told the publication**. “I’ve been working with a writer on my book, Brutally Honest, and it has been unbelievably traumatic reliving an emotionally abusive relationship and confronting so many massive issues in my life.

According to [this dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/publication), **publication** can mean:

> n.
>
> 1. the act of publishing a book, periodical, map, piece of music, engraving, or the like.
> 2. the act of bringing before the public; announcement.
> 3. the state or fact of being published.
> 4. something that is published, esp. a periodical.

None of them seems fit. I guess **publication** means *publishing house* or *an agency that provides the publishing service*.

So, what does it truly mean here?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/mel-b-reveals-she-apos-225321534.html).

Comment: I think it has been liberally used but I think "Publisher" would have been a rather  suitable choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of metonymy, where **the publication** refers to one or more *human representatives* of the publication (the organizational entity), such as a reporter and/or editor and/or publisher.

Compare:

> I told the company about the defect in its product.

We cannot speak directly to a company, of course. We speak (eventually) with a human contact there.

Comment: But according to the dictionary, none of 4 definitions tells *publication* can mean the organizational entity.

Comment: @dan : You should write to the dictionary and tell them about it. Oh, and you'd better see if **dictionary** can refer to the organizational entity while you're at it, and tell the dictionary about that too, if applicable.

Comment: As a second language learner, I just rely on dictionaries too much. Maybe, that's not a good way.

Comment: @dan:  We can do this with any "manned" entity. So you would not expect to find "can also refer to the organizational entity" under every such noun. *Why not call the lost and found and ask them if they have your glasses.*  or *You should tell the website of their error.*

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's the fourth sense of the definition that you quoted:

> 4. something that is published, esp. a periodical.

It's not being used *literally*. It doesn't mean that she held a newspaper in her hand and spoke to it. Instead, she was speaking to somebody who represented the newspaper.

In a previous paragraph from the same story that you cited:

> “I have made the decision to go into a proper therapy [program] in the next few weeks, but it has to be in the UK because I am very, very British and I know that will work best for me,” she told *The Sun* in a statement on Sunday.

So, the publication in question is *The Sun*. Rather than repeating *The Sun* again, the author chose to use a common noun instead—in the same way that pronouns are used in place of names.

Note that saying "she told *The Sun*" is *also* not to be taken literally. As with "she told the publication," "she told *The Sun*" just means that she spoke to somebody working at the company.

The company has the same name as the actual newspaper itself and is being used in a general sense. You could consider it to be an idiomatic use of language.

> If you don't give me money to keep quiet, I'm going to go to *The New York Times*.

In a similar fashion, this means that the person is going to walk into the office building of the company *The New York Times* which produces the newspaper *The New York Times*. (And, by implication, talk to somebody there in order to make known some piece of scandal.)

It would actually *not* be idiomatic to say "*The New York Times* newspaper agency" or "*The New York Times* publishing house" because we use a shorter form of expression in normal communication.

Comment: The sun is more like a publisher rather than a publication in this case in my view.

Comment: @dan Although correct, I, personally, would not refer to it as a *publication* as the author of the story did. I would refer to it as a *newspaper*.

Comment: but a publication could just be a newspaper. I can understand "she told The Sun", because The Sun can stand for the company's name. But publication has no way to stand for a company.

Comment: Or maybe, the publication here does refer to the publication company or agency?

Comment: @dan *I'm going to give that publication a piece of my mind!* I have no problem understanding this as meaning that you're going to complain to somebody at the company responsible for publishing something you've read. (The use of *publication* as opposed to *magazine* or *journal* or *newspaper* is an odd specific word choice—but the principle is the same.) In this news story, *publication* is referring to *The Sun*. A publishing company (at least with books) often produces several imprints. Here, *the* publication is more specific—the group of people responsible for one in particular.